# How do I change the image to the clicked image?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to have the clicked image change using a callback function and animation.
With the following code, when I click on an image in the list, the animation is applied, but the image shows the default value, sample1, and I cannot change the image.
How can I change the image to the one I clicked on?

```js
"use strict"
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#image_list a").click(evt => {
    let newImage = $("#image_list a").attr("src");
    evt.preventDefault();
    $("#image").animate({
      opacity: 0,
      "margin-left": "-100"
    }, 1000, () => {
      $("#image").attr("src", newImage).animate({
        opacity: 1,
        "margin-left": "+=100"
      }, 1000);
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <h1>Please click the image you want to display</h1>
  <img id="image" src="sample1.jpg" alt="sample1">
  <div id="display">
    <ul id="image_list">
      <li>
        <a href="sample1.jpg"><img src="sample1.jpg" alt="sample1"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="sample2.jpg"><img src="sample2.jpg" alt="sample2"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="sample3.jpg"><img src="sample3.jpg" alt="sample3"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Your code is already working, you're just reading the wrong property from the wrong element. You need to change `$("#image_list a").attr("src")` to `$(this).attr("href")`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: After I change $("#image_list a").attr("src") to $(this).attr("href"), it's still same error I have.

Comment: Are you sure? Looks like it works fine to me: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/jn90fL72/

Comment: I got the correct output when `$("#image_list a").click(function(e) {` not `$("#image_list a").click( e => {`. I don't understand what's the difference between click(function(e)) and click(e =>) though. Anyway, thank you for teaching me.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise your first example is using an arrow function. That affects the scope of the function contents, so you instead need to replace `$("#image_list a").attr("src")` with `$(evt.currentTarget).attr("href")`: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/jn90fL72/1/

Comment: now I make sence what I got. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Also, please don't mix jQuery and ES6.

```js
"use strict"
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#image_list a img").each(function (index) {
    $(this).click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var newImage = $(this).attr("src");
      $("#image").animate({
        opacity: 0,
        "margin-left": "-100"
      }, 1000, () => {
        $("#image").attr("src", newImage).animate({
          opacity: 1,
          "margin-left": "+=100"
        }, 1000);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<main>
    <h1>Please click the image you want to display</h1>
    <img id="image" src="sample1.jpg" alt="sample1">
    <div id="display">
      <ul id="image_list">
        <li>
          <a href="sample1.jpg"><img src="sample1.jpg" alt="sample1"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="sample2.jpg"><img src="sample2.jpg" alt="sample2"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="sample3.jpg"><img src="sample3.jpg" alt="sample3"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </main>
```

Comment: When answering a question please provide details of what you changed and why it corrects the issue. This is so that the OP, and future visitors, can understand and learn from your response.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).